# Hibernate Reverse Engineering File

Tags: hibernate

Can I turn off the generation of the parent field below in Hibernate's Reverse Engineering file (hibernate.reveng.xml)?

```
Class Parent {
    private Set children = new HashSet(0);
}

Class Child {
    private Parent parent;  // don't want this
}
```